# Should you apply for a Careers account if you are more interested in a web design?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I'm really interested in Careers, it seems like a very good way to find employers in the field of programming. My question is about using Careers for finding a job in web design, as opposed to web development. Would it be wise to use Careers for that, or is there an alternative better suited for web design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely no harm in having your CV/resume on Careers; it doesn't cost you anything to do. Careers isn't *just* for programmers. I see some sysadmin and data jobs being advertised. If you're not wanting to be a programmer, though, you should probably expect there to be less jobs in the area you wish to enter.

Which brings me to my next point; if you're looking for a job go out and look. Don't rely on *one* website, whether it's Careers or your alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. The reason why I wanted to ask is because the 'invite only' model on Careers seems a bit intimidating for someone who is better at web design than development or programming. The reason why I want a Careers account is because it puts more emphasis on skills relevant to the area of work I'd like to go into, unlike Linkedin for example, which is a bit too generic for me.